# Query about exponents

Tags: python-2.7, exponent

What would be a good way to check if a number x, can be expressed as the sum of digits of x, to the power y.

For example, 512 works because 5 + 1 + 2 = 8, and 8^3 = 512.
   I just need help with the general approach, and not really the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is a mathematical approach, but the brute-force method looks sufficient here: calculate the sums of digits of `x` (5 + 1 + 2 = 8 here) and try every possible exponents until the result is greater than or equal to `x` (8^1, 8^2, 8^3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math

def check(n):
    # sum digits and take the logarithm of input according to sum
    l = math.log(n, sum(int(e) for e in str(n)))

    # if diff is very small, then yes it can be expressed
    return l - int(l) < 1e-6, int(l) # skip second if only check is needed

check(4) # True, 1
check(512) # True, 3
check(511) # False, 3
```